# parent wrapper with absolute position, how to make width auto fit content inside,

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/rs659rLh/5/

How to keep the `.label` tag width auto fit the content inside (make span next to input)
I think problem is the wrapper `.dropdown-list` set position absolute but I need that?  I tried set the `.dropdown-list` position top bottom left right zero but still not work  and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337056/div-with-unspecified-width-absolute-positioning) not work too...

according https://stackoverflow.com/a/7337237/1575921 seems the only way is set the `position:absolute;` wrapper specific width (auto or 100% both not work)

```css
/* config */
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
}
.clearfix >div, .clearfix >li, .clearfix >span, .clearfix >ul, .clearfix >input {
  float: left;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
input, span {
    display: block;
}
/* end: config */

.dropdown-list {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li>top</li>
            </ul>
            <span>icon</span>
        </div>
        <div class="container relative">
            <ul class="dropdown-list absolute">
                <li>
                    <div class="label clearfix">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{name}}">
                        <span>{{name................}}</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You want label next to input?

Comment: I want the span inside label next to input

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you see, but you have two labels and only one is with the class dropdown-list which has background-color property.

That's the problem. You must put a class with background on both classes if you wanna background for both.

Now, if you need one div with same size of other, you must set this width on css or use javascript to be dynamic.

---

If you wanna set background color on label tag directly, you must write directly on label, without span tag, otherwise, set on parent tag.

---

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-list absolute">
                <li>
                    <label class="clearfix label-blue">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="{{name}}">
                        label text
                    </label>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* config */
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul, li {
    margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
}

input, span {
    display: block;
}
/* end: config */

.dropdown-list {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.label-blue {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 10px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `position:absolute` from your `<ul>`. You do not assign any coordinates or dimension here. So why the absolute positioning ?

Then get rid of

```
input, span {
    display: block;
}
```

If you want two elements to appear next to each other you cannot make them both block elements without floating them. Block elements always come with a "line break" at the end.

You can either:

- Leave it out, so `input` and `span` will be inline elements
- keep the block but float both elements to the left
- mark them as inline-block if that serves your purpose

**ADD:**

Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/rs659rLh/7/ is that what you try to achieve?

The problem you have where is that you insist to use an absolutely positioned list element. The issue is that parent elements do not strech to accomodate all the content within its absolutely positioned children. If a child element is bigger than its parent the cnten just floats over or gets cut off.
Therefor you have to define the dimensions of the parent element. which is quite inflexible. I did set:

```
.container{
    width: 200px;    
}
```

just to show how it works. All in all: your markup seem sto be way overcomplicated for the little you are trying to chieve here. Maybe you should rethink the whole process.

Comment: thanks for reply , but I need that ul be absolute position

Comment: then you would have to set explicit positions and dimensions. setting "width: 100%;" on the <ul> would make it take all the place the container offers. Then use the containers to position the whole thing.

Comment: did you test it? because I tried width `100%` or `auto` or `display: table;` or `white-space: nowrap;` on the position absolute wrapper or on `.label`, all not work

Comment: I did. I extended my answer to try to explain whats the issue her.

Comment: thanks so it seems still have set up the container actually width?