# Max width of absolute positioned element

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I have a centered div (using absolute positioning and transform:translate(-50%,-50%) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776915/how-to-center-absolutely-positioned-element-in-div/8273750#8273750)). When the content of the child div is short everything works fine. When the content is long, then the child div width is limited to 50% of the container div (probably because left is set to 50%).

Is there a way to allow the child div to expand to the full width only when the content is long?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">short</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">long long long long long long long</div>
</div>
```

**Edit**: I found an explanation that helped me wrap my head around this in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7337237/1400366) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in an additional nested element to allow yourself more control over dynamic positioning and scaling of the elements in question.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.child-inner {
    background: lightgreen;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"><div class="child-inner">short</div></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child"><div class="child-inner">long long long long long long long</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't center vertically.

Comment: My solution was not intended to center vertically, only intended to address OP's initial concern: "Max width of absolute positioned element" - which it has. I don't find your downvote justified.

Comment: Thanks for the description of your intention, I removed the downvote and let the OP decide.

Comment: Appreciate it @cyrix

Answer (score 1):

Just add an `display: table` to the child div, this should give you the desired result.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.child {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">short</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="child">long long long long long long long</div>
</div>
```

If you could use `flexbox` you can also do this:

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.child {
  background:lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">short</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">long long long long long long long</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Changed position to relative to work in firefox, but don't know if that's what you want.